# VBA Object Variable Not Set when execute SQL

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working in this code and I don't know whats wrong with the code.

Everything works fine until it get to execute the query.

Here's the code:

```
Dim i As Integer

ConnectDB
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
MsgBox (lastrow)

For i = 2 To lastrow
    get_id = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value
    col1 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
    col2 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value
    col3 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Value
    mySQL = "UPDATE pegawai SET nama = '" & col1 & "', alamat = '" & col2 & "', tlp = " & col3 & " where id = " & get_id & ""
    MsgBox (mySQL)
    oConn.Execute (mySQL)  <---- ERROR HERE
    Set oConn = Nothing
Next i
oConn.Close
```

When I run this code I get an error object variable or with block variable not set. And when I add

```
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
```

it produces an error

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

and this the code for my connection

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Public Sub ConnectDB()
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=localhost;" & _
    "DATABASE=belajar;" & _
    "USER=root;" & _
    "PASSWORD=;"
End Sub
```

Why does it get wrong? I appreciate when you all could help.

Comment: Don;t set it to Nothing in the loop.

Comment: Yep. Agree with @MikeCheel. Also later in your code, you should close it first before you set it to nothing.

Comment: Okay I got it know! Thank you very much. But why I should move set oConn = nothing ?
could someone explain it to me?

Comment: ConnectDB creates an instance of ADODB.Connection as OConn. when i=2, you terminate the oConn object by setting it to nothing. When next time, i=3, VBA fails to run the execute method of oConn as it has got 'nothing'. For the sake of understanding, if you call ConnectDB after set OConn=nothing, your code will run fine. But its a very bad practice to create and terminate instances in loop. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move out `Set oConn = Nothing` from FOR loop.

```
Dim i As Integer

ConnectDB
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
MsgBox (lastrow)

For i = 2 To lastrow
    get_id = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value
    col1 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
    col2 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value
    col3 = Sheet1.Cells(i, 11).Value
    mySQL = "UPDATE pegawai SET nama = '" & col1 & "', alamat = '" & col2 & "', tlp = " & col3 & " where id = " & get_id & ""
    MsgBox (mySQL)
    oConn.Execute (mySQL)  <---- ERROR HERE

Next i
oConn.Close
```